# Webview showing nothing white screen

Tags: android, webview

Android webview display white screen instead of loading the website.The website perfectly opens when I open it from web browser, I am using following code Here is the code please help me what can i do for it

**AndroidMainifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.aditya.aditya">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

package in.aditya.aditya;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.pdf2jpg.net");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st you try to load simple url like www.google.com it's work or not check it

Comment: check with another web site

Comment: you code working fine in my device make sure your device has INTERNET connection

Comment: yes i have internet connection

Comment: implement override methods in WebViewClient and check their status

Comment: Google.com open perfectly but when I am using my website not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview.setWebViewClient() method to check whether the url is being loaded or not. It has override methods like **onPageFinished()**,  **onPageStarted()** etc...!!

Try below code :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d("Log-->> ", "onPageStarted: ");
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("Log-->> ", "onPageFinished: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Log.d("Log-->> ", "onReceivedError: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
                Log.d("Log-->> ", "onReceivedHttpError: ");
            }
        });
```

You can check the logs to see if your URL is being loaded correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have added the internet permission in your manifest

And also check the System android webview is updated. Earlier there were some issues found like blank white page